# Is there a way to create a dictionary with consecutive numbers for values?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm working on a classification task and need to turn a list of labels into one hot output for my model. For this, I'm trying to find some neat one-liner to turn a list of potential labels into a dictionary with values that consecutively ascend. So a simple list like: `['a', 'b', 'c']` would turn into a dictionary `{'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2}`. This is easier for the one-hot encoding. So far, I've tried using the dictionary's length to do this, but I think in line loops get performed before a function because when I try `categories = {i:len(categories) for i in labels}`, it yields all values as 0. I can do it using bigger loops and such, but I feel I'm missing some really obvious trick. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
lst = ['e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
data = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(set(lst))}
print(data)
```

Output

```
{'e': 0, 'c': 1, 'a': 2, 'b': 3}
```

Comment: Smashed it mate, cheers.